# qcow2 images on zfs dataset?

Tags: zfs

I am fairly new to ZFS and considering whether using qcow2 disk images on a zfs dataset or a zvol is the better choice in general. Then perhaps depending on what OS to be used on the VM guest. I'm setting up KVM on Ubuntu 22.04 with a mdadm mirror for the OS and zfs raid10 using 4 additional disks for the zpool.

Several VM guests will be FreeBSD where I will want to use root on zfs and a separate zpool for data. This already gives me the zfs features for snapshots, send/receive, dedup for data, etc. I'm thinking the best backend for this VM would be a qcow2 image on a zfs dataset? The dataset can be snapshotted and managed by the host as well as the zfs filesystem within the VM guest. And putting a zfs filesystem on top of a zvol just doesn't sound right.

Perhaps all the VM guests should use qcow2 on separate datasets for snapshot, especially since I'm learning in this document of snapshot limitations for zvols?

https://jrs-s.net/2016/06/16/psa-snapshots-are-better-than-zvols/

I've also read comments from some that putting qcow2 on zfs is bad due to one cow filesystem on top of another cow filesystem causing more wear of the SSD drives. Can someone provide their experience with either?